# UIDatePicker rendered incorrectly on smaller screen sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uidatepicker

I have a date picker inside `UITableViewCell` constrained to top,right,bottom and left. And when I run my app on iPhone with smaller width like iPhone 5s and older it is rendered with strange lines and clippings.
[image]

On iPhone 6 and iPad everything is ok. What can cause that problem?

Running release iOS 9.0 `13A344`, Xcode 7.0 `7A220`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in that the height of the cell containing the date picker was 215.5 (default is 216) so that rounding cell height fixed the problem.